# Reading data from USB using C#?

Tags: c#, usb

I do not want to read serial port nor other possible easy shortcuts please. I would like to know how to read a USB port in my laptop using C#.
whether you can suggest a site or explain the flow of the process i will greatly appreciate your help

Comment: Read _what_ from your USB? Anything plugged in? If a RS232 device is connected I know some easy shortcuts. Oh, wait...

Comment: Do you want to read from the raw device (like a driver) or do you want to read from a specific device type? The first one would probably only be possible through heavy P/Invoke (not worth the hassle). The latter would be device dependend.

Comment: Read data from what? Is it from a device e.g printer? USB is just a standard medium. what is the source of the data.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do development for USB, Jan Axelson's (the author of USB Complete) [website](http://janaxelson.com/usb.htm) is usually a good place to start.

Edit: Assuming it's a HID you want to communicate with [this](https://www.developerfusion.com/article/84338/making-usb-c-friendly/) article could be useful and includes C# samples.

Answer (score 1):

The assumption here is that you want to read data on Windows. Here is a code sample:

```
    public override async Task<byte[]> ReadAsync()
    {
        return await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var bytes = new byte[ReadBufferSize];
            //TODO: Allow for different interfaces and pipes...
            var isSuccess = WinUsbApiCalls.WinUsb_ReadPipe(_DefaultUsbInterface.Handle, _DefaultUsbInterface.ReadPipe.WINUSB_PIPE_INFORMATION.PipeId, bytes, ReadBufferSize, out var bytesRead, IntPtr.Zero);
            HandleError(isSuccess, "Couldn't read data");
            Tracer?.Trace(false, bytes);
            return bytes;
        });
    }

    [DllImport("winusb.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool WinUsb_ReadPipe(SafeFileHandle InterfaceHandle, byte PipeID, byte[] Buffer, uint BufferLength, out uint LengthTransferred, IntPtr Overlapped);
```

All code and samples (including other platforms) can be found here: https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Device.Net