# How to read in signals from USB in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, usb

I am working on my own project to read in signals from a a guitar to USB and i'm having issues on how to implement reading in the signals. I want to be able to play a note on a guitar and the computer will read the frequency via the USB. I do not know if i have to find the serial port and continue from there or if there is an easier way to go about this. Can anyone please provide me with references or examples?

Also, I would need to most likely thread this process in order to keep trying to read in any information received while my program runs.

UPDATE:
I ended up reading the guitar as a Microphone instead of trying to read it as a USB device. It now works.

Thank You,
Brian

Comment: You might fing this post helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053977/reading-data-from-usb-using-c?rq=1

Comment: Hard to say. Does the guitar have documentation telling you what protocol it uses? Serial port access would be the easiest, but it's going to depend on if your guitar is sending serial data.

Comment: Ill take a look at that Darshan! Jim i am trying to find out what protocol it uses, and what type of data is transmitted. I figured it transmitted analog signals because it is usually used for recording music. I'll keep researching.